# restrict access with a hidden input

Tags: php

Ive been struggling with this for a day or two. Not just the coding but explaining the situation precisely. I have a static form on a page, "download-registration.php" when you submit the form (validated CS and SS) it then takes you to "download-software.php" where you can well, download the software. I do not want "download-software.php" to be accessible from anywhere but "download-registration.php" and ONLY after you submit the form. This is the problem I was having with a session based restriction, you could go to "download-registration.php" and alter the url to get to the download page.

I think I need to create a variable (random 1, 65335)? insert that value into a hidden input on click and make sure it matches to a value on the "download-software.php" page?

How do I go about this? does it need to be done this way or is there a better way? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make whatever you have that *processes* the form you want to force them to submit also add a variable to the session. Then check to see if that variable is set on the download page.

My guess is that with your earlier session-based approach you were setting something in the session when the form was *loaded*, but you need to do it when you process it instead if you want to make sure they submit it first.

#### Edit:

display_form.php:

```
// ... display the form, you don't need to set any $_SESSION here ...
```

process_form.php

```
session_start();

// ... process the form ...

$_SESSION['form_processed'] = 1

// ... redirect to download page ...
```

download_page.php

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['form_processed'] != 1) {
    // user never submitted form, reject them ...
} else {
    // user submitted the form, show them the download page
}
```

Comment: @Amber - thats exactly right. I was loading the Session variable when the page was loaded. I need to do it when I process the form. I don't know how though, Id appreciate some help!

Comment: Assuming you're using PHP to process the form, just do the assignment to `$_SESSION[]` as part of the form processing code.

Comment: @Amber, yes, Im using PHP to process the form, but honestly Im the Creative Director and am short of resources atm. So, I set the variable on the form page, submit it's value with a hidden input then i get lost. Can you use $_POST = $_SESSION[] and then on the final page the if statement?

Comment: Don't set it on the form page at all. *Just* set it in the PHP code that's processing the form, and *just* read it on the download page.

Comment: @Amber - awesome. I can see how it works now. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Amber - It works in that if you try and hit the page directly it kicks you to another, but I can't get it to work on form submission. Is it possible Im just putting the session start(); and the "$_SESSION['form_processed'] = 1;
" in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common. You see this in large PHP projects like WordPress, CakePHP, etc.

There are many ways, essentially you just need to create a validity token that is generated and passed from your registration form. You can then clear this token on your software page based on your logic.

You can use a random number, `md5()`, `uniqid()` or whatever. There's also an [nonce library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795970/how-does-this-php-nonce-library-work) out there.

Comment: I was using "$authReq=$_SESSION['authReq']=rand(1,65535);
" on the form page and passing it with a hidden input. But I can't get the end page to have the same value, the form processor also doesn't pass any info to the end page, it just redirects there upon submission.

Comment: Then you need to check it before the redirect in you *form processor*.

Comment: How? Man if I knew how I wouldn't be asking. Im a designer/front end developer/CD. This is unknown but doable for me

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you knew more from your OP. You'd have to post most on your *form processor*. However, looks like **Amber** got it above.

Comment: I understand the theory, and if it were a script I wrote Id have a better chance at the application. The processor is tied in with a bunch of crap from SUGAR CRM, and i can't seem to get the session stuff in the right place.